# Alternative for real-time audio program Voice Meeter

Tags: sound, alternative, audio-recording

I want to edit my audio real-time.

On Windows there's Voice Meeter & (required) Virtual Audio Cable, I want to edit out my keyboard clicks (by adding a noise gate), any way to do this here in Ubuntu?

**A tutorial on how to setup would be appreciated.**

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/Audio

Comment: Perhaps an answer could be built from https://forum.pdpatchrepo.info/topic/1840/simple-noise-gate/13 and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToPureDataIntroduction

Comment: This question is too vague, and demands too much out of an "answer." It is not a simple question being asked, but is requesting a complex tutorial on configuring real time audio systems on Linux.

Comment: Pulsemeeter is a really good alternative! Link: https://github.com/theRealCarneiro/pulsemeeter

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to mix audio in Puseaudio similar to voicemeeter, but not so easy to add noise gate that i know of.

Better to use [JACK](http://jackaudio.org/) sound server for mixers and effects.

For mixer that will also host effects try: [non-mixer](http://non.tuxfamily.org/wiki/index.php?page=Non%20Mixer)

Answer (score 1):

You can use *Audacity* which is an audio waveform editing platform, with many plugins and tools for editing audio files. Or you can use a DAW application like *Ardour* which you can use to edit audio and filter it through plug-ins to get your final product.

There's also *abgate* which is a noise gate plug-in, that can be used with Ardour. Some others may also get installed when you install Audacity and Ardour, and there are several other plug-in packages available to install as well, which may also include other noise gate options.

You can simply install either of them from *Ubuntu Software* and then just start using them.

Comment: Audacity is not for real-time

Answer (score 0):

After trying all the hacks and tools (Audacity, audio recorder etc )
Finally found this Open Broadcaster Software ([OBS](https://obsproject.com/download#linux)), which is super easy and just does the job.

In Settings → Audio, I was able to select:

```
. Audio output (Either desktop or earphone or bluetooth also possible)
. Mic - (Desktop | earphone)
```

For Source, I selected Screen Capture (XSHM) to capture the entire desktop or can keep it blank as well.

To install:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:obsproject/obs-studio && sudo apt install obs-studio`